# Reading tar archive in C

Tags: c, tar, archive

I tried to read archive like this:

```
int fd = open("file.tar", O_RDONLY);
char* ans = malloc(512);
read(fd, ans, 512);
printf("%s\n", ans);
```

But it shows only header name of the file from the first line. But arhive also contains the code of the file. How I should read whole tar arhive?

Comment: Headers in tar files are 512 bytes. Read further to get the file contents.

Comment: Examine headers to get size of contents.

Comment: @MikeCAT I changed size from 512 to .st_size(i got it from stat). I made loop which reads each time and I'm printing the content without "\n". I see that now all okay but when it comes to print the header it shows incorrectly. How do you think what is the problem?

Comment: The problem should be that your program contains some bugs or inproper specifications. `%s` is for printing strings, so it will stop printing at `'\0'`. Here is [a documentation about tar file format](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for detailed help.